# Prove a differential equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> The partial differential equation $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=c^2\left(\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dz^2}\right) \tag{$*$}$$ is the three dimensional wave equation.
>
> In the case of spherical symmetry, for example waves emanating from a point source, we can find a relatively simple form of the solution.
>
> (a) Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ (so that $r$ represents the distance from a poitn $(x,y,z)$ in space to the origin). Show that $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dz^2}=\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}+
> \frac 2r \frac{du}{dr}$$

I am uploading the question as a picture since I have no idea how to format that.

I am very confused as to how I would answer a).

For the left side, i could isolate each of $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}, \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}$$
But how do I get $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}$? I don't see an equation $u$, so how would I differentiate it in terms of $r$?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting.

Comment: this is solved by a "straightforward" application of the chain rule.

Comment: One doesn't "prove a differential equation". One can solve a differential equation. One can write a differential equation. One can verify a function is a solution to a differential equation, but not prove.

Comment: Clearly it is not straightforward to me, if I am asking this question. 
Okay, I profusely apologize for using the term "prove" instead of "solve." Can anybody actually help me?

Comment: @Bob: It is a "change of variable" in a differential equation. Admittedly it is somewhat confusing but not really difficult. Try to follow [the example of Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables_%28PDE%29#cite_note-2), especially the advice in the gray box.

Comment: In your case the "old" variables are $x,y,z$ and the "new" ones are $r, \theta, \phi$. The "old" function is $u=u(x, y, z)$. You can write $u(x, y, z)=v(r)$, since by assumption the "new" function $v$ is radial, that is, it does not depend on angular coordinates. Now get your hands dirty with computations based on the chain rule.

Comment: Actually are you sure the question is correct? I think the RHS is missing a few other terms.

Comment: I think the RHS should be $$u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \phi}u_{\theta\theta} + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\phi\phi} + \frac{\cot \phi}{r^2}u_{\phi}.$$

Comment: @Nameless: You are right but the text mentioned "spherical symmetry", meaning that there is no dependence of $u$ on $\theta$ and $ \phi$.